# WPF: Selecting an item in (virtualized) TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a virtualized `TreeView` and am successfully using the mechanism described  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407130(v=vs.100).aspx) to select a given domain object in the view (expanding the path to the object accordingly), but the tree is always realized fully, which is prohibitively slow for my case (several thousand items).

Is there a better way of getting from the object in a domain hierarchy to the tree 
item instead of this brute force method? I know the path to the item in the domain hierarchy, so I would like to realize only those items that lie on the path to the item to be selected, but I have not found out how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method I've used in the past is to also include an `IsExpanded` property binding to a `ViewModel` object (which represents your visual `TreeItem`).

You can then walk the path from your leaf node back to the root of the tree and setting `IsExpanded` to `true` as you go which means no brute force nasty non-MVVM compliant code in the code behind of your XAML to do so.

Comment: This would require a wrapper around my domain objects, but it's a nice and ingenious way of achieving what I want.

Comment: That's essentially what a `ViewModel` is - a wrapper/adaptor for presentation-related purposes around your domain (model) objects. ;)